# How can I add some style to title of side bar block?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I want to add some style to my drupal 8 Sidebar menu, I want to create something like below image with **Font awesome** and css:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this thing entirely using the `CSS` and `FontAwesome` module, I have just tried in my trial site and posting the image of block title as below, I guess you are looking for the same.

[image]

The CSS code I have used is as below,

```
#block-yourblockID {
    .block-title {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 70px !important;
      background: #0166c3;
      color: #fff;
      }

  .block-title:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     content: "\f100";
     float: right;
     background: #0156a2;
     padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
     color: #fff;
     } }
```

Now, for your title and its content you can adjust padding and margin for your fit. Also you can adjust the padding and margin of block to fit the entire title same as block width.

Answer (score 2):

1. First add `position: relative` as a style to the containing element (most likely the `nav` element.
2. Add a pseudo element after the `h2` element, which you probably want to have your specificity include the class of the nav element.
3. Style the pseudo element with `position: absolute; right: 0;`
4. Tweak the styles of the `h2` and `h2:after` blocks to suit your needs.